# конструктор отчётов (WPF C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, report

Нужно создать программу для создания отчётов. Должно быть 3 функции.

1 Конструкторское меню, где создаётся отчёт

2 На этот отчёт накладываются поля которые можно редактировать не трогая сам отчёт

3 Этот отчёт идёт на печать, или в ворд. Главное что-бы отчёты могли "стаковаться", т.е. чтобы на каждый отчёт не уходило по 1 листу

В общем, посоветуйте в каком направлении копать.

Comment: Копать удобнее в сторону готового софта, на эту тему масса поделок как конечного продукта, так и фрии/коммерческих контролов например для C#, в которых уже все это реализованно.

Comment: Это учебная практика 1 курс) 
Кристал репорт вроде бы только для ВинФормс, а я ничего кроме ВПФ не знаю. Нужно создать не просто таблицу или что-то подобное, а... вот в общем скрин pp.userapi.com/c849528/v849528782/12211/7q2BJLoZjNU.jpg Нужно создавать такое же, и + то что написано ручкой как-то переносить из базы данных(допустим из тхт) на это, и отправить на печать. Думаю второе можно сделать просто добавив возможность добавлять текстбоксы на опред места, а потом самой прогой скринить их

Answer (score 2):

А ещё в создании отчётов поможет Crystal Reports for Visual Studio.
Как раз реализует то, что вам надо.

1. Создаёте объект или список объектов, который передадите в Report как источник данных.
2. Добавте в Report специальные поля для ввода, которые можно обрабатывать не затрагивая данные в отчёте.
3. Печатайте или сохраняйте в word, excel или pdf

Comment: Кристал репорт вроде бы только для ВинФормс, а я ничего кроме ВПФ не знаю. Нужно создать не просто таблицу или что-то подобное, а... вот в общем скрин https://pp.userapi.com/c849528/v849528782/12211/7q2BJLoZjNU.jpg Нужно создавать такое же, и + то что написано ручкой как-то переносить из базы данных(допустим из тхт) на это, и отправить на печать. Думаю второе можно сделать просто добавив возможность добавлять текстбоксы на опред места, а потом самой прогой скринить их

Comment: CrystalReports и для WPF

Comment: И то, что на фото сделать с CrystalReports вообще не проблема.